# mark a number on plot axis - R plot

Tags: r, plot

[image]I'd like to mark a number on the x-axis of a plot in R. For example, circle or highlight the number. Any idea of how to do it?

I was thinking of plotting a circle with a transparent background on the current plot. However, I couldn't find a way to do it right and exactly place it on the number I want which is below the x-axis.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Adding the red circle is what I am looking for]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I added plots I can generate (very basic example) and what I am looking for.

Comment: @MrFlick any thoughts on this?